# Can a polynomial contain logarithms?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I know polynomials cannot be divided by a variable and cannot contain non-whole positive number exponents. However I just want to double check my understanding of the definition when it comes to logarithms.

Would $\log_2x$ be considered a polynomial?

Comment: No, polynomials are sums of terms of the form $ax^n$ where $a$ is constant and $n$ is a non negative integer.

Comment: What could be considered, and in fact is, a polynomial (say, a real one), is for example $\;\log_215\cdot\,x^3\;$

Answer (score 2):

No, a polynomial takes an input, say $x$, and returns the sum of many (but a finite number of) $ax^n$, where neither $a$ nor $n$ depend on x in any way, and $n$ is a natural number, but may be different for each part of the sum. $x \to \log x$ can not be written this way.

Answer (score 2):

By *definition*, a polynomial $p(x)$ over a ring $R$ is of the form:

$$p(x) = \sum_{k=0}^n c_kx^k$$

Where the $c_k$'s are elements of $R$ and $n$ is finite.  In pre-calculus, $R$ will most likely be the integers, the rational numbers, or the real numbers.